# Including a prebuilt static/shared NDK lib, inside another NDK lib project

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

So what im trying to do is:

1. Build a rendering plugin in C++ for the NDK (pass it a bitmap + textureID and it renders the bitmap on texture). This works fine.
2. Add the rendering plugin to a C (for NDK) project that uses ffmpeg to decode videos, each frame of the video is passed to the rendering plugin to display.

I can get the rendering plugin to build into the C project, and the relevant files are moved to the `Obj/local/` or `libs/` directory (I've tried both static and shared builds for the renderer). However I can't get it to include in the actual C code.

The directory looks like this:

[image: Directory Structure]

It wont link when i try add a `#include <renderplugin.h>` to my code, saying `file or directory could not be found`

My `Android.mk` in the `jni` folder:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := NativeMediaPlayer
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := NativeMediaPlayer.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lz -lGLESv2
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libavformat libavcodec libavutil liblog libswscale NativeRenderPlugin

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#ffmpeg
$(call import-add-path, ../)
$(call import-module, NativeMediaPlayer/external)
#render plugin
$(call import-add-path, jni)
$(call import-module, prebuilt)
```

And the `Android.mk` in the `prebuilt` folder where the plugin is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libNativeRenderPlugin
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/libNativeRenderPlugin.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: _"But my library does not have a .h file"_. Then how do you plan on using it? Do you have the function prototypes somewhere else? If so, why not put them in a header for this library?

Comment: In any case, you don't `#include` a `.a` or `.so`file - you link against them in your makefile.

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob at the whole NDK thing. I didn't know that function prototypes needed to be placed in a .h file. Is there a good resource for finding out how to do this properly? The NDK docs are a bit 'lightweight'.

Comment: You don't _need_ to put them in a header file. But that's the typical way of doing things. This isn't specific to Android or the NDK.

Comment: Well the renderer plugin only has a couple external methods. If i wrote a `.h` file with the function prototypes inside it would that be sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it was something to do with where the library was placed, after moving them into the same folder as the ffmpeg libs (and updating the makefiles) the include is working correctly now.